# How to find all jira issues which are assigned to me between given dates?

Tags: jira, jql

I would like to filter out all issues which were assigned to "XYZ" between 1st May to 5th May.

Note:- assignee may be changed in between so i used 'was'

I wrote this query

```
assignee was XYZ AND updatedDate < "2017/05/06 00:00" AND updatedDate > "2017/04/30 00:00"order by updated DESC
```

But, all is correct except this fails on one special case.

This is giving me those issues too which were assigned to me earlier before these dates --

because these issues may be updated in these dates range.
I could not sort it out as there is no such thing assignedDate in Atlassian.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 4):

You can combine the *WAS* operator with a *DURING* clause, e.g.

```
assignee WAS xyz DURING ("2017/05/01","2017/05/05")
```

The JQL operators [documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirasoftwarecloud/advanced-searching-operators-reference-764478341.html#Advancedsearching-operatorsreference-WASWAS) also contains some examples.